# Angular access methods of parent routes from child routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

So to explain clearly my problem, I have a component for each of my entities in my application like Author component and Book component. And for each of them I will have two child which is a list component and a form component.

So basically my route configuration look like this :

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'author', component: AuthorComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'author-list', component: AuthorListComponent },
            { path: 'author-form', component: AuthorFormComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'book', component: BookComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'book-list', component: BookListComponent },
            { path: 'book-form', component: BookFormComponent }
        ]
    }
]);
```

In my AuthorComponent for example I have a method to delete an author that call the service :

```
deleteBadge = (event): void => {
    // Call delete service
    this._badgeService.delete(event).subscribe(
      result => {
        // Good
      },
      error => {
        // Error
}
```

My question is how can I call that method from my route child (author list or form component) knowing that I can't call it like a normal child component using event.

PS: I put method (and many other) in the parent because I need to access to it in both child components and so to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Use a shared service with an observable to notify listeners about events they need to react on.

Comment: I feel the service method is really ugly.. I mean if I have to pass a simple small information for example to a child I need to create a whole new service for it ? Doesn't look good for me @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: If you think a service is ugly for that you won't enjoy Angular a lot. That's the way to go for communications between components that are not parent/child (or siblings) statically within the same components template.

Comment: Günter is right. Maybe you can have a general communications service which unites several communication observables.

Comment: @MeMeMax I have no problem with service itself but seems heavy for me to create a whole new service to pass a string to be honest. But your idea of a a general service to manage communications between components looks really good, do you have a reference for me ?

Comment: Consider using Angular CLI. You would generate a whole new service with one line in your git bash.

Comment: You can of course use a generic message bus implementation. I don't know one, but I'm quite sure there is on out there already. I still don't see what the problem is with a specific service class only for this single channel. It's just a handful lines of code and easy to reason about. If you provide it at the parent component (instead of on the module), the scope is very limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard practice is to use a shared service for [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). However, if you still want to avoid using a shared service, you can use the [Injector API](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector).

In your child component, `AuthorListComponent` for example, do the following:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthorComponent} from "./author.component";
// ....

constructor(private injector:Injector){
    let parentComponent = this.injector.get(AuthorComponent);
    parentComponent.deleteBadge('String passed from AuthorListComponent');
}
```

Here is a link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9mjfa?file=app%2Fauthor.component.ts).

Comment: Ah that's really interesting. Do you know if it's a good practice to do tho or not ?

Comment: thats not the standard practice, as I wrote in my answer as well. Its another way since you didn't want to use a shared service.

Comment: What about using **@ViewChild()** instead of this? I think we can also achieve the same result, but I am not sure which one is better?

Answer (score -1):

Use a communication Service which unites several communication observables.

An example can be found in the official Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service